# Creating an X509 Certificate in Java without BouncyCastle?

Tags: java, x509certificate, jce

Is it possible to sanely create an X509 Certificate in Java code without using the Bouncy Castle `X509V*CertificateGenerator` classes?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ability to sign certificates is not part of a standard Java library or extension.

A lot of the code that is needed to do it yourself is part of the core. There are classes to encode and decode X.500 names, X.509 certificate extensions, public keys for various algorithms, and of course, for actually performing the digital signature.

Implementing this yourself is not trivial, but it is definitely doable—I probably spent 4 or 5 full days the first time I made a working prototype for certificate signing. It was a *fantastic* learning exercise for me, but it's hard to justify that expense when there are usable libraries available for free.

Comment: Is this still accurate as of 2017?

Comment: No, the code snipped uses obsolete cryptography (MD5withRSA or SHA1withRSA in the Javadoc) for signing the certificate. Instead, I would recommend using either SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA512withRSA or SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withECDSA and SHA512withECDSA depending on the level of security you are designing for.

Comment: @DanielGartmann It's not clear what "code snipped" you are talking about. Is your "no" a reply to the previous commenter?

Comment: @erickson yes, I am obviously answering user674669's question. What I meant with "code snippet" is the code displayed in the first 2 answers below (in the grey area containing the source code).

Comment: @DanielGartmann The commenter is asking if my answer is still true in 2017. I think it is; you can't sign certificates out of the box, you have to build it yourself. So, if you are saying that's wrong, can you explain why? But your second comment makes it sound more like you are saying the other answers are wrong in the way they've applied the APIs that are provided (and, with that, I agree).

Comment: So, there is no class in the JCA (Java Criptography Arquitecture) that allows this, right?

Comment: @CarlitosWay Right. No supported API for it.

Answer (score 90):

Yes, but not with publicly documented classes. I've documented the process [in this article](http://bfo.com/blog/2011/03/08/odds_and_ends_creating_a_new_x_509_certificate.html).

```
import sun.security.x509.*;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException

/** 
 * Create a self-signed X.509 Certificate
 * @param dn the X.509 Distinguished Name, eg "CN=Test, L=London, C=GB"
 * @param pair the KeyPair
 * @param days how many days from now the Certificate is valid for
 * @param algorithm the signing algorithm, eg "SHA1withRSA"
 */ 
X509Certificate generateCertificate(String dn, KeyPair pair, int days, String algorithm)
  throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
{
  PrivateKey privkey = pair.getPrivate();
  X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();
  Date from = new Date();
  Date to = new Date(from.getTime() + days * 86400000l);
  CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
  BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
  X500Name owner = new X500Name(dn);
 
  info.set(X509CertInfo.VALIDITY, interval);
  info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
  info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, new CertificateSubjectName(owner));
  info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, new CertificateIssuerName(owner));
  info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(pair.getPublic()));
  info.set(X509CertInfo.VERSION, new CertificateVersion(CertificateVersion.V3));
  AlgorithmId algo = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.md5WithRSAEncryption_oid);
  info.set(X509CertInfo.ALGORITHM_ID, new CertificateAlgorithmId(algo));
 
  // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
  X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
  cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);
 
  // Update the algorith, and resign.
  algo = (AlgorithmId)cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG);
  info.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM, algo);
  cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
  cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);
  return cert;
}
```

Edit 2021 - unfortunately this approach won't work under Java 17, as the `sun.*` hierarchy can't be accessed. So it's back to BouncyCastle or a roll-your own ASN.1 serializer.

Comment: A very good tip. Saved me from importing the dreaded (and beloved) Bouncycastle lib. Bloat begone!

Comment: Is there a way to do it that DOESN'T involve calling in to sun.security.x509.*? Given that it is, in fact, not something you're supposed to use.

Comment: Excellent. Saved me a lot of work. Code is nice and clean. I am editing in the code to make sure it does not disappear is the blog goes down.

Comment: how do you add extensions?

Comment: With JDK 8 this should be: info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, owner);
            info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, owner);

Comment: The change @AxelFontaine mentioned is described here https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7198416

Comment: @meno Check line 2512 on https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java

Comment: How does this code set the BasicConstraint to true for the self-siged cert?

Comment: To set the basicConstrains (CA flag, path length) check: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/x509/BasicConstraintsExtension.html

Comment: X509CertInfo from which dependency is that?

Comment: X509CertInfo was sun.security.cert. But it's worth noting that this will no longer work under Java 17 as the sun.* hierarchy is locked down.

Comment: @MikeB eh, I think the whole community is struggling with this issue. IMHO it's quite terrible that they blocked X509CertInfo without providing alternative. I made a general question about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441994/how-to-generate-self-signed-certificate-in-java-with-jdk17 It would be awesome if there would be slim BouncyCastle that would allow only certificate generation.

Comment: For Android, these classes can be found in [this library](https://github.com/MuntashirAkon/sun-security-android)

Answer (score 14):

```
import sun.security.x509.*;

import java.security.cert.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Example {
    /**
     * Create a self-signed X.509 Example
     *
     * @param dn        the X.509 Distinguished Name, eg "CN=Test, L=London, C=GB"
     * @param pair      the KeyPair
     * @param days      how many days from now the Example is valid for
     * @param algorithm the signing algorithm, eg "SHA1withRSA"
     */
    public X509Certificate generateCertificate(String dn, KeyPair pair, int days, String algorithm)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        PrivateKey privkey = pair.getPrivate();
        X509CertInfo info = new X509CertInfo();
        Date from = new Date();
        Date to = new Date(from.getTime() + days * 86400000l);
        CertificateValidity interval = new CertificateValidity(from, to);
        BigInteger sn = new BigInteger(64, new SecureRandom());
        X500Name owner = new X500Name(dn);

        info.set(X509CertInfo.VALIDITY, interval);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, owner);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, owner);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(pair.getPublic()));
        info.set(X509CertInfo.VERSION, new CertificateVersion(CertificateVersion.V3));
        AlgorithmId algo = new AlgorithmId(AlgorithmId.md5WithRSAEncryption_oid);
        info.set(X509CertInfo.ALGORITHM_ID, new CertificateAlgorithmId(algo));

        // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
        X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);

        // Update the algorith, and resign.
        algo = (AlgorithmId) cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG);
        info.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM, algo);
        cert = new X509CertImpl(info);
        cert.sign(privkey, algorithm);
        return cert;
    }

    public static void main (String[] argv) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Example example = new Example();
        String distinguishedName = "CN=Test, L=London, C=GB";
        Certificate certificate = example.generateCertificateOriginal(distinguishedName, keyPair, 365, "SHA256withRSA");
        System.out.println("it worked!");
    }
}
```

I liked vbence's answer, but I kept getting the following exception:

java.security.cert.CertificateException: Subject class type invalid.

After lots of attempts to find out *was* a valid subject class I found out that X509CerInfo wanted an instance of X500Name.

```
1 info.set(X509CertInfo.SERIAL_NUMBER, new CertificateSerialNumber(sn));
2 info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, new CertificateSubjectName(owner));
3 info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, new CertificateIssuerName(owner));
4 info.set(X509CertInfo.KEY, new CertificateX509Key(pair.getPublic()));
```

So lines 2 & 3 needed to change to

```
2 info.set(X509CertInfo.SUBJECT, owner);
3 info.set(X509CertInfo.ISSUER, owner);
```

Answer (score 4):

All the basic components to make a self-signed certificate (signing, X509 encoding etc) are available in JRE. Unlike BC, Sun's JCE doesn't provide any public calls to sign a certificate. However, all the functions are available in Keytool. You can simply copy the code from keytool to do this. The method you need to copy is `doSelfCert()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, Keytool uses `sun.*` classes for this. So this won't work with every JRE. However here is the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you want to do (and probably your definition of "Sanely"). As ZZ Coder pointed out, you can create a self-signed certificate directly by copying [keytool](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/security/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java.htm). But I don't believe you can create a PKCS10 certificate request object with the standard JCE, which you probably need to do if you want to create standard CA-signed EECs.

Comment: Hm, why not? Keytool can convert a self signed to a csr, you just need to copy that code as well.