# Is there a way to make Java trust a certificate if it is in Windows trusted certificates list?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I am writing a fairly simple client application in Java which uses Apache HttpComponents to send few HTTP requests to a server and process its responses. I am stuck with connecting to SSL server though, as all the test servers I have access to are using certificates signed by our corporate root certificate (distributed by AD domain controllers) and this root certificate is not trusted by default.

I did a fair amount of googling in the last few days, but did not find a solution which works for me. All solutions I found (most of them are here - on Stack Overflow) are coming down to 2 paths:

**1. Disable certificate trust completely.**
Well, this might be fine for tests, but I want trust check enabled in the release version of the application and thus I have to test it too.

**2. Add self-signed certificate to the Java cert store using keytool.**
This would be easy enough to do for tests, but not for the release version. In my environment I know what certificate I need to trust/add, however potential users of the application will be outside of my environment and thus they will have their own different set of certificates.

Here's some links for solutions I mention above (there are much more out there, but they all come down to the same 2 solutions):

- [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)
- [Java 7 - SSL how to trust all certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680670/java-7-ssl-how-to-trust-all-certificates)
- [Programmatically adding a trusted cert in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767047/programmatically-adding-a-trusted-cert-in-java)
- [How can I get a list of trusted root certificates in Java? (This link is helpful if you want to see what Java is trusting by default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508050/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-trusted-root-certificates-in-java)

---

What I want (ideally) is to have Java code checking certificate received from Server against Windows certificate storage and trust it as long as Windows does (if there is a multi-platform solution - even better). Or, alternatively, export all trusted root certification authorities from Windows cert storage and import them into Java trust storage. The general idea is to trust a server certificate if user's machine trusts it, no matter what kind of certificate it is (self-signed, commercial, corporate AD cert, etc.).

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!