# How to generate self-certificate from root ca cert in java

Tags: java, ssl, proxy

I am writing Java program proxy (man in the middle proxy). When the client connect to my proxy, i want to the server will send its self-certificate.

My problem is: How to auto generate self-certificate for every domain(using any tools: keytool, openssl,...) and sing to existed root ca?
I want to when i imported root ca to browser(ex Firefox), it will not showing warning when client connect server through my proxy and i can decrypt data between the client and server.

In this case: I have two solutions:

1) I am writing a sh file include multiple command generate self-certificate and then execute it by java(Runtime.getRuntime().exec)

2) I found an module [iaik_jce](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/old/iaik/x509/X509Certificate.html) has an constructor method
`cert = new iaik.x509.X509Certificate(server_cert.getEncoded());`: server_cert be get from statement: `server_cert = (X509Certificate) socket.getSession().getPeerCertificates()[0];`
but it is not supported all algorithm. I get an exception with google, facebook,...

Comment: why do you want to create a new self signed cert each time?

Comment: @ScaryWombat , if the browser check the response certificate not match for domain, it will show the warning.

Comment: This answer covers how to generate x509 certificates, its not simple and uses sun api's but ti should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle

Comment: @Magnus thanks. Very useful  for me.