# Eclipse Bouncy Castle method X509v1CertificateBuilder not found

Tags: eclipse, certificate, bouncycastle, builder

I want to build a certificate with Bouncy Castle in Eclipse.
I used the functioin X509v1CertificateGenerator but it is deprecated. When I want to use the Certificate Builder it seems like that there is no Certificate Builder in the Bouncy Castle.
[image: Certificate Builder Problem]

What is the problem here that I can't get the functioin Certificate Builder in BC ?
I am also not able to `import org.bouncycastle.cert.*;` the other deprecated imports work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle

look here. Maybe it helps

Comment: the problem is I don't get access to the org.bouncycastle.cert.* to be able to use the Certificate Generator.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded also

```
bcpkix-jdk15on-156.jar
```

file, now it works.