# How to sign a certificate using BouncyCastle or Java 11

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I've an existing certificate (C1), including private key, and not marked as a CA and trusted from an internal root-CA (C0)
I want to use it to:

Client side:

- Generate a new keypair (C2)
- Sign the keypair using C1, so that it has validation path C2<C1<C0
- Use C2 to perform SSL client auth

Server side:

- Accept the SSL client cert
- Validate the chain regardless of C1 not being a CA

So far I've found articles on how to use a generic key to sign a new key:
[Creating an X509 Certificate in Java without BouncyCastle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615871/creating-an-x509-certificate-in-java-without-bouncycastle)

However:

- The resulting C2 is not trusted and thus not accepted when negotiating => We'll probably have to disable client cert validation on the apache side and perform it on the Java side
- The above article hints at using private sun JDK methods: any hints on how to do that using standard jdk 11 classed or BouncyCastle?

Comment: If C1 is not marked as a CA that is not possible under X.509.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is pointed out in comments by Boriss the Spider, certificate is not allowed to sign other certificates if any of the following conditions are not met:

1. Certificate subject must be CA via [Basic Constraints](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.9) certificate extension. See my [blog post](https://www.pkisolutions.com/basic-constraints-certificate-extension/) on how basic constraints work in practice and how certificate chaining engine reacts to violation.
2. Certificate must include `certKeySign` usage in [Key Usage](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) certificate extension

> Validate the chain regardless of C1 not being a CA

it would be hard to disable basic constraints and key usage extension validation and retain other validation steps, this may require to disable client certificate validation at all. This is a simple PKI misuse that opens various vulnerabilities because you cannot implement proper certificate validation.

Comment: Mh, so you believe there's no reliable way to check if C2 has been correctly signed by C1 without messing around?

Comment: I would say "No". Check https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-6 to figure out what checks you will have to implement yourself. I would NOT recommend to run PKI in the way you are trying to. You must have a proper CA certificate to sign other certificates. And even if you get it -- I would recommend to use specialized CA software for this. Do not roll your own crypto.

Comment: All in all I understand that the risks associated with using this kind of single-use sub-certificates largely outweight the potential advantages, thanks